# How to explode string using capital letters as delimiter?

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to achieve this using php explode but I am having trouble in doing it.

here is my code

```
<?php
$capitals = array("A","B","C");
$word_break = "brandonBjakeCsullano";

$count = 0;

while ($count <=2)
{

$break =  explode($capitals[$count++],$word_break)


}
echo $break[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo $break[1];

?>
```

using above code I can have this result:

**brandonBjake**

**sullano**

and this is what I am trying to achieve

**brandon**

**jake**

**sullano**

Appreciate your help.

Any strategy is acceptable rather than my style of doing it..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you use a capital letter as a string delimiter? I'd strongly recommend using something else to identify the split / explode.

Comment: yes I also want to use "-" or "/" but my boss wants me to do it using Capital  letters and put it in an array.. appreciate if someone could solve the problem..

Comment: `$break` is getting reset in `while` loop. you are just getting result of third explode.
Epodax in right about using a single non- alphabet delimiter.

Comment: yes I want to use another delimiter other than letters but our files is not going with that flow..

Comment: can somebody advice me on what code below runs faster? because they are all working well now is the speed matters ..

Comment: Nangada napud mong Brandon

Comment: thanks bro that could be challenging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always the good old [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) which lets you use a regular expression to split a string into an array.

Something like (untested):

```
$names = preg_split( '/[A-Z]/', 'brandonBjakeCsullano' );
print_r( $names );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try along with `str_replace` and `explode` as

```
$capitals = array("A","B","C");
$word_break = "brandonBjakeCsullano";
$word_break = str_replace($capitals, '/',$word_break);
print_r(explode('/',$word_break));//Array ( [0] => brandon [1] => jake [2] => sullano )
```

**Edited**
and if you want to echo then simply use it as

```
echo implode('<br>',explode('/',$word_break));// instead of print_r
```

1)If you use [`print_r(explode('/',$word_break));`](https://eval.in/374063)

```
OK (0.008 sec real, 0.008 sec wall, 14 MB, 71 syscalls)
```

2)If you use [`echo implode("\n",explode('/',$word_break));`](https://eval.in/374066)

```
OK (0.008 sec real, 0.009 sec wall, 14 MB, 42 syscalls)
```

3)If you use [$res= explode('/',$word_break);
foreach($res as $value){ 
    echo $value."\n";

}](https://eval.in/374069)

```
OK (0.012 sec real, 0.015 sec wall, 14 MB, 44 syscalls)
```

Comment: I see no more loops required nice strategy :)

Comment: Yep that can be achieved easily without using loops

Comment: Check my edited answer it'll echo your values without using loops

Comment: yes I am able to introduce this to my boss and he choose this answer thanks bro !!  continue sharing your talent

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one to try :

```
<?php
$capitals = array("A","B","C");
$string = "brandonBjakeCsullano";

$count = 0;
$capitals = array("A","B","C");
$string = "brandonBjakeCsullano";
$string = str_replace($capitals, '/',$string);
$res= explode('/',$string);
foreach($res as $value){ 
    echo $value."<br>";   
}
?>
```

**Output:-**

```
brandon
jake
sullano
```

For your reference [Click Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/z0vcll)

Comment: may I know if what query style above would run faster?

Comment: i am not getting what you asking?

Comment: I mean there are answers here that is working well but may I know which one works faster ?

Comment: if you want pretty styles output my answer is faster and looking good.

Comment: You have to decide best answer according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$capitals = array("A","B","C");
$word_break = "brandonBjakeCsullano";
$arr=str_split($word_break);
for($i=0;$i <=strlen($word_break);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<=2;$j++){
        if($arr[$i]!=$capitals[$j]){
            $flag=TRUE;
        }
        else{
            $flag=FALSE;
            echo '<br>';
            break;
        }

    }
    if($flag==TRUE){
        echo $arr[$i];
    }
}

?>
```